# Git workflow from local to bitbucket/github hub to live webserver

Tags: git, github, hosting, lamp, bitbucket

I would like to setup a workflow that enables pushing local changes to Bitbucket or Github (but ideally the former) that then updates a live site hosted on my lamp VPS server. Is this possible? I remember working some time ago with a team that had a similar setup but with Github.

There is an article by Joe Maller http://joemaller.com/990/a-web-focused-git-workflow/ that describes a similar approach where the hub is another directory on the same webserver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That kind of post-push action is managed:

- on GitHub with [webhook (post-receive hook)](https://help.github.com/articles/post-receive-hooks)
- on BitBucket with [Service hooks](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Manage+Bitbucket+hooks) as "[broker](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Write+brokers+%28hooks%29+for+Bitbucket)"
  See more at "[POST hook management](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/POST+hook+management)".

In both cases, those hooks generate a POST hook which passes a payload to your third-party web application through its API.
Your third-party application is responsible for receiving and transforming the payload.

That means your lamp VPS server needs to have a listener in place able to interpret said payload.
you can see an example of a script managing a deployment [in this article](http://brandonsummers.name/blog/2012/02/10/using-bitbucket-for-automated-deployments/), by doing a `git pull`:

```php
     // Make sure we're in the right directory
      exec('cd '.$this->_directory, $output);
      $this->log('Changing working directory... '.implode(' ', $output));

      // Discard any changes to tracked files since our last deploy
      exec('git reset --hard HEAD', $output);
      $this->log('Reseting repository... '.implode(' ', $output));

      // Update the local repository
      exec('git pull '.$this->_remote.' '.$this->_branch, $output);
      $this->log('Pulling in changes... '.implode(' ', $output));
```